# Read images from local disk using torch7 while those images saved in different subfolders?

Tags: lua, luajit, torch

I have images which have saved in the desk. The data saved as follow:  4 main folders (1,2,3 and 4) each folder has 26 subfolders ( these subfolders represent the class of images (A, B, C, D, ..,Z)). Each of these subfolder contains more than 500 images. However, I am looking for file or code in torch that can read these images. In MATLAB I could wrote a code but here I find it confuse. Could you please advise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is use [Penlight](http://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/index.html) (the library [is installed](https://github.com/torch/distro/blob/54f060f/install.sh#L68) when you install Torch).

Penlight provides [`pl.dir`](http://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/libraries/pl.dir.html) that makes it easy to scan files in (sub-)folders. For example what you can do is:

```
local pl = require('pl.import_into')()
local t = {}
for i,f in ipairs(pl.dir.getallfiles('/data/foo', '*.jpg')) do
    t[i] = { f, pl.path.basename(pl.path.dirname(f)) }
end
```

This creates a list of pairs (filename, class label = "A" or "B" ...). Of course you are free to change the file pattern (`*.jpg`) or to omit it (in such a case Penlight will simply list all files). You can also load the images on the fly:

```
t[i] = { image.load(f), pl.path.basename(pl.path.dirname(f)) }
```

Or do that right after when manipulating `t`.

Comment: Many thanks , I think, it works but I have other question please. When I load my images I received this message (PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (not enough memory)) My number of my images not that big nearly 100.000 images and I use macbook with 16gb RAM.

Comment: In such a case do not load all your images on memory, i.e. keep the filename like in the 1st code snippet above and only load a batch of images when you need it (a.k.a. lazy loading).